# Tool or environment <MakeFeatureLayer_management> not found, Failed to execute (AttributeSearch)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I have created a arctoolbox with scripts in it. In the script, I set the source script file (a python file), my question is when I run this python using a batch file, it won't cause error, unfortunately when I use the arctoolbox script to run the python script, I got the following error: 
**Tool or environment  not found, Failed to execute (AttributeSearch).**

The following is my python script details:

```
'''----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Tool Name:     SelectLayerAttribute
 Source Name:   SelectLayerAttribute.py
 Version:       ArcGIS 10.2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'''
import arcpy
# Set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/Users/lyao/Desktop/PUB_GIS_Tagging/GIS_DMS.gdb"
# get user supplied path, layers and fields
Value = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
# Make a layer from the feature class
feature = "c:/Users/lyao/Desktop/PUB_GIS_Tagging/GIS_DMS.gdb/BQ_Segment_test"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(feature, 'lyr')
where = '"DrainName" = ' + "'%s'" %Value
#arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION"," \"ROAD_NAME\" = "'%s'" % Value ")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION",where)
```

Comment: I am so sorry the python script is so messy,repost:

Answer (score 1):

You would need to edit your `where` clause:

```
import arcpy
# Set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\ArcTutor\BuildingaGeodatabase\Montgomery.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True #to be able to overwrite existing feature layer
# get user supplied path, layers and fields
Value = r"foo"#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
# Make a layer from the feature class
feature = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\ArcTutor\BuildingaGeodatabase\Montgomery.gdb\Landbase\Parcels"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(feature, 'lyr')
where = """Landuse_co = '{0}'""".format(Value)      #'{0}' for strings and {0} for numeric input
#arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION"," \"ROAD_NAME\" = "'%s'" % Value ")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION",where)
```

In case you will run your scripts on other types of geodatabases (not only file), it might be beneficial to build in the [AddFieldDelimiters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/AddFieldDelimiters/03q300000091000000/) arcpy function which figures out what field delimiters should be used in an SQL expression depending on the format of the queried data.

In Python, building expressions surrounded with triple quotes is both easier to read and understand. You can read more about using queries in Python at Esri help here ([Specifying a query in Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001r000000)).

Comment: Thank you Alex, but I still got the same error :(

Comment: Would you please update your question to include the exact error message? Can you run this script I've published above in some Python IDE in debugging mode to see which line gives you the error? So, you've authored a script tool in a custom toolbox. Did you make sure you have supplied the input parameters (since you use arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) you would need to have 4 parameters defined and the 4th will be your right part of the SQL expression).

Comment: Hi Alex, when I run the script using PythonWin, it works fine. When I use it in a arctoolbox as a source script, it throw the following error: Tool or environment not found, Failed to execute (AttributeSearch). I am sure the 4th parameter is what I defined in the script.

Comment: Hi Alex, one strange thing is when I uncheck "Run Python script in process", it works fine. don't know why.

Comment: I don't understand why do you get this error message when running this tool in process. I am not able to run this script tool when not in process :) however, it is nice that you got it working in some way, so you could do some research later on.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I really need to do some research on it.